# Zoom/Scroll in tree of life graphic with huge and partially dense data

Tags: algorithm, canvas, scroll, graphics, zooming

[Image here ------------------- Tree of life](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Bdh.jpg)

[image]

I have this kind of tree of life graphic which can be zoomed / scrolled visualizing binary tree which has about 7000 nodes.

Each node has distance value so its height is fixed. and sure, parent node has always higher height value than child's

Because the distance is fixed, a situation I uploaded above could happen.

The blue area contains more than 1000 nodes, but the distance between each node is very very tiny (less than 0.00001px when visualized).

On the other hand, the red area, which has much bigger area than blue area, has less than 10 nodes.

The problem is, this graph is hard to implement zoom / scroll action.
To visualize blue area in detail, at least we should make 1 pixel of canvas to be equal 0.00001px of actual data, which means, zoom 100000 times. So when a single zoom action makes +1 zoom, a user has to make this action 100000 times. that's really painful.

So instead of +1 zoom, let's take some reasonable value, like +10000.
now to visualize blue area well, user has to perform zoom only 10 times.

While with this solution, what if zoom is done on red area? after zoomed, the user expects to see still some nodes on red area, but suddenly the user see nothing because zoom value is so big.

Anybody has a good idea? :)

Comment: If you set zoom as a multiple of the current zoom you get a logarithmic zooming factor. This also has the effect that at any zoom a single zoom step will increase a visible region by the same amount. This will allow quicker zooming in and out. To zoom in `scale *= scaleFactor` and to zoom out `scale *= 1/scaleFactor` with `scaleFactor > 1` you could als0 experiment with changing the `scaleFactor` at specific scales..

Comment: @Blindman67 That could be one of reasonable solution. I'll try that and find out whether it works with nice UX.  thanks :)

Comment: Oh and I forgot to say that you pan by mouse drag distance times the current scale. The zoom will work. There is an example of a scale of the universe type of thing where you use the mouse wheel to scale from 1e-35 (planck length) all the way to 10e28 (visible universe)  or thereabouts. 63 orders of magnitude, which is a little more than the 5 you  have.